# phonebook with arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to try a simple implementation of phonebook with arraylist in java.
First I made a class contains what the info. needed and second I want have another class which have methods like getting info and printing them.

and because I want to use array list this is what I've done so far, but the 'print' method keep giving me the error in for loop, is there any one who can help me to optimize my code and why I have this error.

this is the first class :

```
public class PhoneBook {
long number;
String name;
.
.
.
.

getter() and setter();
}
```

The second class with methods:

```
public class PhoneBookMethods {

ArrayList<PhoneBook> phoneBooks = new ArrayList<PhoneBook>();

public void getInfo(PhoneBook phoneBooks)
{

.
.
.
}
public void print(PhoneBook phoneBooks)
{
    for (PhoneBook p: phoneBooks) {// this is where I got the error
//foreach not applicable to type 'PhoneBook'
        System.out.print(p.getName());
        ....
    }
}
```

}

Comment: PhoneBookMethods should be called PhoneBook, and PhoneBook should be called PhoneBookEntry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your for-each loop, change

```
for (PhoneBook p: phoneBooks)
```

to

```
for (PhoneBook p: this.phoneBooks)
```

so that you would be accessing the `phoneBooks` arraylist, not the argument of the `print` method.

**EDIT:**

You can use the "**this**" keyword to make your code much more "explicit".
For the example, in your case you have an argument called `phoneBooks` that has the same name as your `ArrayList` (member variable). So to explicitly differentiate between the two of them, use `this.phonebooks` to access the member variable `phoneBooks`(the ArrayList), and use `phoneBooks` to refer to the argument.

Comment: ...argument of the `print` method, which is useless and should be omitted.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm just confused that how 'this' help me accessing the 'phoneBooks arraylist', maybe I'm a little confused about the meaning of 'this' here I know about the use of it in other places but here I haven't use it with array list, could you describe it just a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use instance variable `phoneBooks` then no need to pass any param in the method `print()`.

```
public void print()
{
    for (PhoneBook p: phoneBooks) {// this is where I got the error
//foreach not applicable to type 'PhoneBook'
        System.out.print(p.getName());
        ....
    }
}
```

OR if you really want to pass param rename the param name

```
public void print(ArrayList<PhoneBook> phoneBookList)
{
    for (PhoneBook p: phoneBookList) {// this is where I got the error
//foreach not applicable to type 'PhoneBook'
        System.out.print(p.getName());
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: If print is a proper method it should operate on a field, i.e., the second version is not appropriate. It might be, as a static method, and then the parameter type should be Collection, not ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

public void print(PhoneBook phoneBooks)

Your parameter phoneBooks masks the field (the array) also named phoneBooks. So compiler tries to treat parameter as list and failes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually at first you have some design issues. The way you think what is a PhoneBook is invalid. You should consider a phonebook something holds several phones on it. Therefore, you may have a phone class like below:

```
public class Phone {

    private String number;
    private String name;

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

And a phonebook class responsible for holding those phone objects:

```
public class PhoneBook extends ArrayList<Phone> {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (Phone phone : this) {
            stringBuilder.append("----------------------------\n");
            stringBuilder.append("Name:" + phone.getName() + "\n");
            stringBuilder.append("Number:" + phone.getNumber() + "\n");
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

It is a arraylist of Phone, nothing more. Thus, you can add or remove a phone directly via phone book. This is how to use it:

```
public class MAIN {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Phone myPhone = new Phone();
        myPhone.setName("Eray");
        myPhone.setNumber("0533XXXXXXX");

        Phone girlfriendPhone = new Phone();
        girlfriendPhone.setName("Canan");
        girlfriendPhone.setNumber("0544XXXXXXX");

        Phone yourPhone = new Phone();
        yourPhone.setName("Bita Mirshafiee");
        yourPhone.setNumber("0599XXXXXXX");


        PhoneBook phoneBook = new PhoneBook();
        phoneBook.add(myPhone);
        phoneBook.add(girlfriendPhone);
        phoneBook.add(yourPhone);

        System.out.println(phoneBook);
    }

}
```

Finally, this is the output:

```
----------------------------
Name:Eray
Number:0533XXXXXXX
----------------------------
Name:Canan
Number:0544XXXXXXX
----------------------------
Name:Bita Mirshafiee
Number:0599XXXXXXX
```

Comment: Good answer but way too complex for a simple solution ;-)

Comment: Thanks, you actually solve the problem. It was good because it reminds me some methods and that by extending it will be so much easier.